# ORA-00972: identifier is too long creating a view

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view, syntax-error

I have this SQL to create a Oracle View but I came across this error
I Already try a lot of approaches and nothing.

```
SELECT * FROM COM_Company 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT NULL  FROM CTM_ServiceCompanySupportGrpAssoc  
WHERE CTM_ServiceCompanySupportGrpAssoc.Company = COM_Company.Company_ID);
```

Another statement was this:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('SELECT * FROM COM_Company WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL  FROM CTM_ServiceCompanySupportGrpAssoc  WHERE CTM_ServiceCompanySupportGrpAssoc.Company = COM_Company.Company_ID)') XML from dual;
```

I need all companies that doesn't have any support groups.

Comment: Edit your question and describe what you want to do with the query.  Sample data and desired results would help.  Based on the error, you have no table or view called `CTM_ServiceCompanySupportGrpAssoc`, because the identifier is too long.

Comment: The issue is column name `CTM_ServiceCompanySupportGrpAssoc` being 33 characters long. Names for tables, clusters, views, indexes, synonyms, tablespaces, and usernames must be 30 characters or less. You must shorten the name to no more than 30 characters for these objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identifier can be up to 30 characters. you defined identifier with 33 characters (CTM_ServiceCompanySupportGrpAssoc) see [dba-oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00972_identifier_is_too_long.htm)

Just reduce the length of your identifier name.

From Oracle 12.2 it will be longer see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/exadata-express-cloud/csdbf/longer-identifier-names.html)

Comment: Ok I decrease the Char number to 20 and is working. Thanks :)